# Radial cursor with Background Image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

I'm trying to create a radial cursor on a site with a background image.

I currently have two problems:

1. It currently works with Chrome, but not with Firefox. I receive a parsing error for "background" when it occurs.
2. On Chrome, sometimes two cursors appear instead of 1 and it appears to be mirrored, which can be seen in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tstyyck4/)

I'm currently using the following code adopted from [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingHighlight/).

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks!

.

CSS:

```
        html { 
      background: url("blocpartylandscape.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
        $(function() {

        var originalBGplaypen = $("html").css("background"),
            x, y, xy, bgWebKit, bgMoz,
            lightColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.75)",
            gradientSize = 100;

        var originalBG = $('html').css("background");

            $('html')
            .mousemove(function(e) {

                   x  = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                   y  = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                   xy = x + " " + y;

                   bgWebKit = "-webkit-gradient(radial, " + xy + ", 0, " + xy + ", 100, from(rgba(255,255,255,0.8)), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.0))), " + originalBG;
                   bgMoz    = "-moz-radial-gradient(" + x + "px " + y + "px 45deg, circle, " + lightColor + " 0%, " + originalBG + " " + gradientSize + "px)";

                    $(this)
                        .css({ background: bgWebKit })
                        .css({ background: bgMoz });


            }).mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).css({ background: originalBG });
            }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To make things simpler for Firefox, I added another HTML element. The element is a container around everything in `body`. I did this so that the `html` element can have its persistent background image and not be disturbed by the competing radial cursor background (which is also an image). Chrome was okay with sharing the `html` element for both the background image and the radial cursor, but Firefox was not.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi egestas in diam vitae elementum. </h1>
</div>
```

I'm using the newly added container as a canvas on which to display the radial cursor.

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;          
}
```

Now, in your JavaScript, I simply use that new container element to show the radial background.

```
$(".container")
  .css({ background: bgWebKit })
  .css({ background: bgMoz });
```

And then for removing the radial cursor.

```
.mouseleave(function() {
  $(".container").css({ background: originalBG });
});
```

Firefox also needs an rgb or rgba value instead of whatever your call to background was returning. That value wasn't a valid argument to the radial background, though the following is valid:

```
bgMoz = "-moz-radial-gradient(" + x + "px " + y + "px 45deg, circle, " + lightColor + " 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.0) " + gradientSize + "px)";
```

You  may want to refactor a bit more. My main goal was to get things working for you. Below is a demo which works in both Chrome and Firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/7d17ufm7/